# how to highlight frame if option button in frame isn't selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to highlight any visible controls in userform that aren't filled out or selected. it works, but it'll still highlight frames even if 1 of the two option buttons are selected.

```
Dim ControlsOfInterest As Collection
```

found a function to identify opt button values within frames:

```
Function OptionGroupSelectionMade(oneButton As MSForms.OptionButton) As Boolean
    Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control

    For Each oneControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(oneControl) = "OptionButton" Then
            If oneControl.Parent.Name = oneButton.Parent.Name Then
                If oneButton.GroupName = oneControl.GroupName Then
                    If oneControl.Value Then
                        OptionGroupSelectionMade = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oneControl

End Function
```

and then the rest of the code is supposed to only identify values not entered when theyre visible

'on initialize

```
Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control
Dim onePage As MSForms.Page

Set ControlsOfInterest = New Collection
For Each onePage In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
    If cmbFundingCategory.Value <> "Req Reduction" Or cmbFundingCategory.Value = "Combo (Unreq'd Dollars + Req Reduction)" Then
    Else
    For Each oneControl In onePage.Controls
        If oneControl.Visible And oneControl.Parent.Visible Then
            If oneControl.Name Like "txt*" And oneControl.Visible Then
                ControlsOfInterest.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
            ElseIf oneControl.Name Like "opt*" And oneControl.Visible Then
                ControlsOfInterest.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
            ElseIf oneControl.Name Like "cmb*" And oneControl.Visible Then
                ControlsOfInterest.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next oneControl
End If
Next onePage
```

to loop through frames to check each one to see if an option button is true?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim colBlankFields As New Collection
    Dim oneControl As MSForms.Control
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strPrompt As String

    For Each oneControl In ControlsOfInterest
        oneControl.BackColor = vbWhite
        If oneControl.Name Like "opt*" Then
            If Not OptionGroupSelectionMade(oneControl) Then
                oneControl.BackColor = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                colBlankFields.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
                strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
             End If
        Else
        If oneControl.Visible And oneControl.Text = vbNullString Then
                oneControl.BackColor = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                colBlankFields.Add item:=oneControl, key:=oneControl.Name
                strPrompt = strPrompt & vbCr & oneControl.Name & " on page " & oneControl.Parent.Caption
            End If
        End If
    Next oneControl
    If colBlankFields.Count <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "some controls need values" & vbCr & strPrompt
    End If
End Sub
```

but I still have values populated in the msgbox from fields hidden until a combobox 'cmbFundingCategory` is supposed to show them

Comment: For any option button you can get a reference to its Parent, check if it's a Frame, then if so loop over the Frame's controls and check if there's at least on checked option button.  FYI typically option button sets should always have only one item checked (if you need different behavior then checkboxes might be more appropriate)

Comment: @TimWilliams i found a solution, but still having problems with it highlighting values that are hidden and not visible until a combobox is triggered to one of two values

Comment: @TimWilliams `If oneControl.Visible And oneControl.Parent.Visible Then` should be preventing this, but its still allowing the msgbox at the end to identify those values even though the combobox hasnt displayed them to the user